# Multi index pandas dataframe and .diff()

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Let's say I have the following multi index pandas Dataframe:

```
                     A    B
Date        Code     
01-01-2017  s1       1    2
            s2       3    1
01-02-2017  s1       2    2    
            s2       3    3
```

Differently from what discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944652/partition-pandas-diff-in-multi-index-level), I do not want that `.diff(1)` operates on the values having the same dates and resetting at each new date, I would like instead that `.diff(1)` provide the following output:

```
                     A    B
Date        Code     
01-01-2017  s1       Nan  Nan
            s2       Nan  Nan
01-02-2017  s1       1    0    
            s2       2    1
```

that is `.diff(1)` makes the differences by blocks specified by differebnt values of the index at level 0 and not within blocks as in the link proposed.
In other words, I want to subtract these two matrices by entries:

```
|2    2|  _  |1    2| 
|3    3|     |3    1|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by second level with [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df = df.sort_index()

df = df.groupby(level=1).diff()
print (df)
                   A    B
Date       Code          
01-01-2017 s1    NaN  NaN
           s2    NaN  NaN
01-02-2017 s1    1.0  0.0
           s2    0.0  2.0
```

because if use first level:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).diff()
print (df)
                   A    B
Date       Code          
01-01-2017 s1    NaN  NaN
           s2    2.0 -1.0
01-02-2017 s1    NaN  NaN
           s2    1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Should we assuming level 0 index is ordered?